# Can mix DDR3 Ram from different manufacturers for My Fujitsu LH532 laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

Following the confirmation by the Fujitsu Apac Service Centre in Singapore (they mentioned that they do not carry the RAM chips for my model and more importantly that I can buy from outside market and plug it in myself), have purchased a Kingston 8GB Ram module.

While at the outlet in Sim Lim Square, have booted into BIOS and confirmed that it is working (recognizable) with the original Samsung 4 GB Ram chip.

Upon reaching home, was a bit uneasy and plugged out the 4GB ram chip and currently only running on the 8GB chip.

Samsung 4GB - M427B5273CH0-CK0
Kingston 8GB - 1UL9U-H9FP2A-2WR1F (1.5V) BPMK1611503 (KVR16S11/8)

Query: Am not sure whether I can use both the memories from 2 different vendors (unsure whether they have any "parity" issues. Appreciate if someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Believe me or not, that kind of question is so common that you should not have problems googling it. It may be possible that someone else has the same exact laptop and faced same issue and still someone else helped him along.

While there are no stupid questions, there are people known  as inquisitive idiots. Making sure you ask right question before fact helps missing that user category...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: yes, you can use RAM from two different vendors in your system.

You have to make sure they have similar parameters before you buy, though.

Fortunately for you they have. It's still not a guarantee they will work, but two mainstream manufacturers should not give grief to one another.